# Not matching the output with the correct output

Tags: python

[image]

```
def interpret(result : [None]) -> str:
    s = ''
    s = s + 'Start state = ' + result[0] +'\n '
    for x in result[1:-1]:
        s += ' Input = ' + x[0]+ '; new possible states = ' + str(sorted(x[1])) + '\n '
    s = s + ' Input = ' + x[0]+ '; new possible states = ' + str(sorted(result[-1][1])) + '\n'
    s = s + 'Stop state(s) = ' + str(sorted(result[-1][1])) 
    return s




           evaluated: Start state = start
  Input = 1; new possible states = ['start']
  Input = 0; new possible states = ['near', 'start']
  Input = 1; new possible states = ['end', 'start']
  Input = 1; new possible states = ['start']
  Input = 0; new possible states = ['near', 'start']
  Input = 0; new possible states = ['end', 'start']
Stop state(s) = ['end', 'start'] == Start state = start
  Input = 1; new possible states = ['start']
  Input = 0; new possible states = ['near', 'start']
  Input = 1; new possible states = ['end', 'start']
  Input = 1; new possible states = ['start']
  Input = 0; new possible states = ['near', 'start']
  Input = 1; new possible states = ['end', 'start']
Stop state(s) = ['end', 'start']
```

31 *Error: Failed `ndfa.interpret(i) == "Start state = start\n  Input = 1; new possible states = ['start']\n  Input = 0; new possible states = ['near', 'start']\n  Input = 1; new possible states = ['end', 'start']\n  Input = 1; new possible states = ['start']\n  Input = 0; new possible states = ['near', 'start']\n  Input = 1; new possible states = ['end', 'start']\nStop state(s) = ['end', 'start']\n"`

The function takes a list and returns a string. I need to return the string in the correct format. 
It seems to me that the output I get is the same as the correct output, but it give me an error. Can someone tell me why it is not correct? Many thanks

by the way the input is   `['start', ('1', {'start'}), ('0', {'start', 'near'}), ('1', {'end', 'start'}), ('1', {'start'}), ('0', {'start', 'near'}), ('1', {'end', 'start'})]`

and the correct output is       '"Start state = start\n  Input = 1; new possible states = ['start']\n  Input = 0; new possible states = ['near', 'start']\n  Input = 1; new possible states = ['end', 'start']\n  Input = 1; new possible states = ['start']\n  Input = 0; new possible states = ['near', 'start']\n  Input = 1; new possible states = ['end', 'start']\nStop state(s) = ['end', 'start']\n"`

I added a picture to show the result I got.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You haven't provided enough information that I can understand what you're asking for. Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the 6th line of the function from `x[0]` to `result[-1][0]`, which seems to work:

```
def interpret(result : [None]) -> str:
    s = ''
    s = s + 'Start state = ' + result[0] +'\n '
    for x in result[1:-1]:
        s += ' Input = ' + x[0]+ '; new possible states = ' + str(sorted(x[1])) + '\n '
    s += ' Input = ' + result[-1][0] + '; new possible states = ' + str(sorted(result[-1][1])) + '\n'
    s += 'Stop state(s) = ' + str(sorted(result[-1][1])) 
    return s
```